# How to parse a line out of a file that contains a certain string with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, trim, whois

With PHP I want to get the content of the line starting with `descr:` out of a whois record from RIPE IP adress ranges, so they should all look something like this:

```
% This is RIPE NCC's Routing Information Service
% whois gateway to collected BGP Routing Tables
% IPv4 or IPv6 address to origin prefix match
%
% For more information visit http://www.ripe.net/ris/riswhois.html

route:        53.0.0.0/8
origin:       AS31399
descr:        DAIMLER-AS Daimler Autonomous System
lastupd-frst: 2011-12-08 23:18Z  195.66.224.97@rrc01
lastupd-last: 2012-01-25 15:18Z  203.119.76.3@rrc00
seen-at:      rrc00,rrc01,rrc03,rrc04,rrc05,rrc07,rrc10,rrc11,rrc12,rrc13,rrc14,rrc15,rrc16
num-rispeers: 98
source:       RISWHOIS
```

So I should get `DAIMLER-AS Daimler Autonomous System` as a result.

How to do this with a minimum of code, I have the record in $whois.

```
<?php 
$whois = shell_exec('whois -h riswhois.ripe.net ' . $ip);
?>
```

Comment: Do not shell out from PHP just to execute a whois command. You have specific libraries in PHP to do whois queries inside of your program or just open a TCP socket on port 43 and read RFC3912 for all details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
$whois = shell_exec('whois -h riswhois.ripe.net ' . $ip);
$result = preg_match('/^descr:\s*(.+)$/m', $matches);
$descr = $matches[1];
```

Note the use of the mutliline (`m`) modifier.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by splitting the string into an array of lines:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $whois);
```

Then loop through them and find the one that starts with `descr:`:

```
foreach($lines as $l) {
    if (strpos($l, 'descr:') === 0) { //We have a winner
        $description = trim(substr($l, strlen('descr:')));
    }
}
```

Or, you know, use a Regex solution like Tim's.

Answer (score 2):

A preg_match solution like Tim's would be optimal but just to put a third suggestion out there for reference and especially for shorter strings. Same thing could be accomplished with:

```
$descr_starts_at = strpos($my_text,"descr:") + 14;
$length = strpos($my_text,"lastupd-frst:") - 1 - $descr_starts_at;

$descr = substr($my_text, $descr_starts_at ,$length);
```

Comment: @rdlowrey:  not necessary, but it sure makes the job a lot easier.

Comment: I voted for Tim aswell, but i think for simpler "searches" regex could be unnecessary or too complicated for beginners to understand.

Comment: @TimCooper You're right ... I kind of meant +1 for strpos in situations when a regex might not be necessary in general ... people seem to forget about it. For this one I'd totally go preg_match. You get a +1 from me too :)